# How do I crop a video clip?

Tags: video-editor, kdenlive

I've recorded a video using `recordmydesktop`, but have unfortunately chosen for capturing the whole screen (1600*896) instead of a small part with geometric 900*690.

How do I crop this video? Preferably in the editor I'm using, Kdenlive, to minimize quality loss. I've tried the Crop, Pan & Zoom and Scale0tilt effects, modifying the pixel ratio, movie size inside project settings options without success. A step-by-step guide would be preferred or at least some hints.

Comment: Have you tried Blender? I could try to find a way and write a tutorial.

Comment: I haven't tried it with Blender, but for suddenly, the crop feature works as expected. I restarted the program after some modifications, but cannot remind the taken steps.

Comment: Would it be meaningful to add answers for other programs such as avidemux and openshot as mentioned in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604224&page=2?

Comment: If a different editor is suggested, it's OK.

Answer (score 17):

Cropping a video can be done multiple ways in Kdenlive.

One way is to set the project to the desired size then set the video to original size so that only the cropped part is visible in the project.

How to do it:

1. Start a new project with the desired crop size.
   If no profile available with required size you should create a new project profile by clicking on **Manage project profiles** button. [image]

Then click on **create new profile**.

[image]

Change the profile settings as required in your case make it 900x690.

2. Import your clip to project bin and add it to timeline.
3. Add **Position and Zoom** effect to your clip.
4. Click on **adjust to original** size in the effect settings.
   [image]
5. Change the X and Y to adjust the position of the cropped region as desired.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I have a 1280x720 clip which I want to crop to Facebook cover image 820x312. When I click 4) adjust to original, Kdenlive makes the clip larger, but still too much height. It is as if this effect always forces the project settings dimensions (820x312) on the clip, whatever size I set it to

Comment: Hi Thomas Lindvig.  
What version of Kdenlive are you using?

Comment: Kdenlive 19.12.1 for Windows.

Comment: [SOLVED] Point 4 in the guide should be "check distort" then it worked for me

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend using another program, `handbrake`. Use the `Loose Crop` option, then switch back to the `Summary` tab to see a visual representation of the crop effect. I found it rendered faster than kdenlive using the crop effect as well.

[image]

Comment: Now a 'Custom' option in a 'Cropping' drop-down but otherwise the same. The 'Preview' window allows you to see the affect your changes will having on the output.

Answer (score 8):

If nothing else works, you could use `mencoder`. It is not an interactive editor and will result in re-encoding of the video. If you can live with that, here's how: `mencoder -oac pcm -ovc x264 -vf crop=900:690:0:0 -o output.mp4 input.mp4` where the :0:0 part is upper left coordinates of the cropped area. You may want to play around with -oac and -ovc options and see which codecs produce the best results. Use `mencoder -ovc help -oac help` to get a listing of available options.

Comment: Works great. Just to say that it can be applied directly on the *.ogv* file produced by RecordMyDesktop.

Answer (score 6):

I am a first-time Kdenlive user myself, but I found this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssk84N9CAE0) suggesting to use the **transform effect**. Worked just fine for me.

I know this is not a detailed guide, but the video explains the gotchas better anyway.

Comment: To those who don't know. You have to drag the transform effect onto the video timeline. Then you'll be shown a window where you can adjust the offset at all sides of the video by a certain number of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to crop and scale up a vertical clip that was embedded in a horizontal video (480p) with huge useless bars on the sides, and I figured out how to do it:

- First read [this answer here from Andyba](https://askubuntu.com/a/1052157/355106) as it has all the screenshots and stuff that were useful for me, but I will say what I had to do differently from there:
- Start by creating a new project with Custom settings, copy the "Vertical HD 30fps" or 60fps project and alter it to your desired final resolution settings, in my case 480p 9:16 or 480x854, save a new copy with a new name, then use that project
- Import your clip into the Project Bin, drag it into the timeline in either V1 or V2 as usual
- In the panel in the top left, click over to the "Effects" tab, search for "Position and Zoom", click and drag it onto the clip in the timeline below.
- If the video preview on the top right is looking funky, such as the V1 and V2 being beside each other as though it is trying to split-screen your video with the other video track, the easy solution is either fully close and reopen Kdenlive, or just hide the other video track with the filmstrip looking button on the left of its timeline in the timeline interface
- Click on the clip in the timeline that you just dragged the effect onto, then in the bottom right corner click on the "Effect/Composition Stack" tab
- The exact settings you will need may vary, but what worked for me was to set the "Size" field to about 320%

I did not need to use the X/Y settings at all but if you do, you may want to start with the little Center Vertically or Center Horizontally buttons in between the offsets and the size fields, then start tweaking those offsets a bit manually if they aren't quite right for you.

Answer (score 0):

### Kdenlive

Installing [Kdenlive 23.08.1 with Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/org.kde.kdenlive), then:

1. Add clip to project bin and drag & drop it to video track.
2. On Effects tab, search for [Edge Crop](https://docs.kdenlive.org/en/effects_and_compositions/video_effects/transform_distort_perspective/edge_crop.html)

   [image]
3. Drag & drop it to video section to crop.

   [image]
4. On the left, on the Effect/Composition stack, tune the crop parameters, checking the results preview on the project monitor (by default in the upper left corner).

   [image]

Done.

---

From [manual](https://docs.kdenlive.org/en/effects_and_compositions/video_effects/transform_distort_perspective/edge_crop.html):

> #### Warning
>
> As of this writing and in version 23.04 this effect still behaves strangely. The parameter values seem to interfere with each other and it is not possible to have all four sides being cropped. It is either top/bottom or left/right and only the last value entered is applied (and then on both sides). Until this is fixed it is recommended to use the [Crop, Scale and Tilt effect](https://docs.kdenlive.org/en/effects_and_compositions/video_effects/transform_distort_perspective/crop_scale_tilt.html).

Based on [this idea](https://www.reddit.com/r/kdenlive/comments/laprmo/comment/glpfv05/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: After using Edge Crop, when I render the project to a file, the resulting file is still the full resolution of the original video - it just has a lot of black space. What am I missing?

Comment: @Guss Not sure. Check your output resolution setup or the warning on the manual (I updated the post)

Comment: I've tried to render to a different resolution by creating a custom _Output Preset_, and with just _Edge Crop_ it was weird - it rendered in the resolution I specified in the preset, but the full video, scaled (with correct aspect ratio) to the resolution I specified. After adding also a _Transform_ effect, the result was what I wanted - a full frame video with just the cropped content and no black borders.